# how to make two divs next to each other

Tags: html, css

unfortunately i dont know how to make these divs(Boxes) next to each other like the picture and put the images of the cars like the image , can anyone please help me

if there is a way with tables or divs please help me to do it

[here is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4PpUl.jpg)

Comment: Where is your code, Did you tried it?

Comment: You can use bootstrapgrid.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.block1{
  background: red;
  height: 150px;
  padding-top: 30%;
}

.block2{
  background: green;
  height: 150px;
  padding-top: 30%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="col-xs-12 text-center">
<div class="col-xs-6">
<div class="block1">
  text
</div>
</div>


<div class="col-xs-6">
<div class="block2">
  text
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: it works but when i view this on a mobile it's not responsive , all the text be overlaped and it's not working well

Comment: use bootstrap frame work, it will work fine for above code. I given link also..can u go through this process...

Answer (score 0):

you can use float:left for your 2 divs inside a parent div

Answer (score 0):

Try this html+bootstrap will work fine for mobile views :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>


<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
     Image 1
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      Image 2
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      Image 3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: it works but when i view this on a mobile it's not responsive , all the text be overlaped and it's not working well

Comment: Look above html will help.